# \submaincmpdplain and \subcmpdplain not working correctly when sub-labels initiated with \initcmpd

Tags: chemnum

I have come across something weird with the `chemnum` package. I am trying to have my compound numbers in the pdf bookmarks. So I am using `\texorpdfstring{}{}` within my section titles. However, the sub-labels are not being printed when using `\submaincmpdplain{}{}` or `\subcmpdplain{}{}`. This only occurs when the compounds have been initiated **with** sub-labels within `\initcmpd{}`. For my document it is vital I use this.

Any ideas for a fix?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{chemnum}
\initcmpd{%
    cmpd.{aa,bb},
    cmpd.cc,
}

\begin{document}
    \cmpd{cmpd.aa}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{aa}.

    \cmpd{cmpd.bb}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{bb}.

    \cmpd{cmpd.cc}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{cc}.

    \cmpd{cmpd.dd}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{dd}.

    \cmpd{cmpd.ee}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{ee}.

    \cmpd{cmpd.ff}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{ff}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: I have already reported this on [GitHub](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues/10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which is fixed in the currrent version v1.2c (2019/10/02):

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{chemnum}[2019/10/02] % v1.2c or newer

\initcmpd{
  cmpd.{aa,bb} ,
  cmpd.cc ,
}

\begin{document}

\cmpd{cmpd.aa}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{aa}.

\cmpd{cmpd.bb}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{bb}.

\cmpd{cmpd.cc}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{cc}.

\cmpd{cmpd.dd}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{dd}.

\cmpd{cmpd.ee}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{ee}.

\cmpd{cmpd.ff}, \submaincmpdplain{cmpd}{ff}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. No matter what I did, I couldn't get the sublabels to work when initiated in the preamble. I used a little workaround instead:

in the preamble:

```
\initcmpd{%
    cmpd
}
```

and right after \begin{document}:

```
\cmpd*{cmpd.{aa,bb,...}}
```

Still doesn't fix the main issue, but works for now...